# Kotlin: How can I avoid autoboxing (garbage) in delegated properties?

Tags: properties, delegates, kotlin, autoboxing, garbage

In my software, I have some various values which use property delegation.

This is a simple similar example showing what I do:

```
class ExampleDelegate<T>(val value: T) {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = value

}

val example by ExampleDelegate(1000) // number larger than 127 (no box cache)
```

What I've noticed, however, is that referring to this value seems to create an autoboxed object (`java.lang.Integer`) on *EVERY* reference. Because the value must be referenced potentially millions or times per second, this results in massive garbage creation for my software; heavy stress is put on the garbage collector.

Is there a way to avoid the overhead? If not directly, are there any clever ways to "emulate" property delegation that are performant?

[image]

Submitted a bug report on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13606

Comment: The example code you posted should not produce any boxing. I don't see any calls to `Integer.valueOf` in the bytecode.

Comment: "On the Java platform, numbers are physically stored as JVM primitive types, unless we need a nullable number reference (e.g. Int?) *or generics are involved*. In the latter cases numbers are boxed." - I guess that this is the problem here...

Comment: just saw that that's what you are told on your bug-report as well

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include that part of the story! I do happen to be using generics as Dmitry Petrov guessed.Updated the question with using generics.

Comment: The suggested solution is to create specialised delegate classes for the primitive values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13606), your app generates garbage because your property delegate is generic, and therefore requires boxing of values. If you use a non-generic property delegate with a primitive type, no boxing happens.